# Linux application get crashed in pthread_create()

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am developing a multi threaded linux application. Sometimes I have noticed application get crashed while creating a thread. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: It's unlikely pthread_create() causes a crash (Check it's return value in any case) and it's *more* likely that the thread function does something that causes the crash. Show your code.

Comment: Code is very large. I am checking with return value now. Will let you know.

Comment: Is it on a 32 bit application and you are creating many threads ? Watch the memory footprint, the process may have run out of virtual memory - by default it needs 10MB for a thread stack.

Comment: Ok. I am checking it now. Will let you know. Was busy with other works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have information like how many threads were running when the crash occur and the stack size?

This type of crash can be caused by stack size overflow or max user processes overflow. When there are lots of thread open this issue can arise. Please check how many concurrent threads are running? are there any thread which is not being closed after its purpose finished?

Comment: got it! Yes you are right. Actually there were lots of thread running unnecessarily. When I closed unused thread the issue is gone.

Comment: Another query, do you know how much threads can be created under a process in linux?